# Where can I see the processor of my Intel Iris Plus Graphics?

Tags: windows-10, graphics

I am using an HP ENVY Laptop-17-cg0002na on Win10 Home edition and Device Manager - Display Adaptors tells me I have a Intel(R) Iris(R) Plus Graphics. I double clicked it but none of the Properties says the model of Iris Plus.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69H46.png)

HP is the manufacturer and its website's spec doesn't go to that level of detail either (https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c06640287#AbT0). Where can I see the processor of this Intel Iris Plus Graphics so I can then look at its specs here https://ark.intel.com/content/www/es/es/ark/products/graphics/197532/intel-iris-plus-graphics.html

Thank you

Comment: You could use a utility like [HWiNFO](https://www.hwinfo.com/).

Comment: That HP spec page states **Microprocessor: Intel® Core™ i7-1065G7** which would lead you directly to this Intel Page https://ark.intel.com/content/www/es/es/ark/products/196597/intel-core-i71065g7-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz.html

Comment: HWInFO worked thanks a bunch ! From there I've come to see that the processor used by the integrated graphics card is the cpu itself as also confirmed by Mokubai, I thought the integrated graphics card would be using its own cpu (like the case of an external graphics card). all clear now, thank you!

Comment: I see where you are coming from @SergioSolorzano, about 15 or 20 years ago "integrated" graphics was built into the motherboard chipset, but on modern systems it is fully integrated with the CPU which gives it faster and more efficient memory access.

Comment: Intel Iris Plus Graphics is the model of GPU